# How to create an iframe using jQuery, and display on page?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
       $('.accordion').load('<iframe src="google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame"></iframe>');
    });
});
```

This can't display the iframe of google.com. Can anyone provide suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: It obviously doesn't work - read the docs of the jQuery `load` function. Besides that, you have quoting issues in your code.

Comment: There is a syntax error in code around iframe src. ("google.com' - started with double quote, ends with single quote)

Comment: FYI: you can't iframe google that way

Answer (score 94, accepted):

jQuery's [load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) isn't used this way. It takes a URL as a parameter, among others, and loads the response from that URL.

If you are trying to create an iframe DOM element, use the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) function to do this and append it where you want:

```
$('<iframe src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame"></iframe>')
     .appendTo('.accordion');
```

or

```
$('<iframe>', {
   src: 'http://google.com',
   id:  'myFrame',
   frameborder: 0,
   scrolling: 'no'
   }).appendTo('.accordion');
```

Answer (score 4):

If .accordion is a container for your iframe try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('.accordion').html('<iframe src="google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame"></iframe>');
});
```

});

And fix that quote syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

2 errors.

1. Use full path (not sure it's necessary)
2. close google.com with double quotes.

   $('.accordion').load( '< iframe src="http://www.google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame">');

(Ignore the space in iframe tag)