# How do I open an iframe if the user presses a key?

Tags: html

I want to make it so that if the user presses for example 'x', my iframe window with a chat opens. If they press x again, it closes.

Current code:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <iframe name ="frame" src="" width="25%" height="300"></iframe>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = e.which;
    if (e.which == 192) {
      var src = $("#frame").attr("src");
      if(!src.trim()) {
        $("#frame").attr("src","http://deadsimplechat.com/+f8ckA/");
      }
      else {
        $("#frame").attr("src","");
      }
    }
});
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode == 88) { // x pressed
        if(myWindow) {
            myWindow.close();
            myWindow = undefined;
        } else {
            myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
        } 
    }
}

var myWindow;

document.onkeydown = checkKey;
```

Use something like this.

Comment: It works when I open it, but when I press the key again to close it, nothing happens. However, when I press the key again, (after the first time I tried to close it), that iframe window refreshes.

Comment: You have to focus on main window and then press X again. Your main window is listening for 'X', not the child window

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = e.which;
    if (e.which == 49) {
      var src = $("#frame").attr("src");
      if(!src.trim()) {
        $("#frame").attr("src","https://www.example.com/");
      }
      else {
        $("#frame").attr("src","");
      }
    }
});
});
```

You can edit the keycode [by finding the proper keycode](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/).
I assume you will have some iframe like this in your code or you can [create iframe from jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179703/how-to-create-an-iframe-using-jquery-and-display-on-page). You can also [remove the ifram from jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118148/jquery-if-statement-and-remove-iframe). Also edit the example source URL to your appropriate site.

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
</div>
```

You have to include the library whenever working with jquery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**
This must be working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            var keycode = e.which;
            if (e.which == 49) {
              var src = $("#frame").attr("src");
              if(!src.trim()) {
                $("#frame").attr("src","https://www.w3schools.com/");
              }
              else {
                $("#frame").attr("src","");
              }
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv">
            <iframe id="frame" src="" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
        </div>
        <input type="text">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should note that you answer requires the use of the jquery library which is not mentioned anywhere in your answer.

Comment: No errors in the console. Edited original post with code.

Comment: @abc12333333 - I have tried this solution and it's working for me. Please try it.